# Online Accounts can't sign into google on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, google, 23.04, online-accounts

I am on freshly-installed Kubuntu 23.04 (KDE Plasma 5.27.4) trying to sign into my google account in system

> Settings → Online Accounts → Add Account → Google

When I select Google, a pop-up window shows up asking for my username. When I put it in and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the window looks like it's loading something, but it never does. When I close it, a message pops up in the Settings window saying

> There was an error while trying to process the request: Access grant not present

Comment: Why, in the love of the lord, no one is solving this looooong time issue? Nor Ubuntu nor KDE accept this as a bug and, like a hot potato, is thrown from one to the face of the other. We're not talking about any minor volunteered distro and they receive tons of money.